# HTML Table: Black background tr on white background

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want a table having a `tr` as black background inside a table which has white background.

```html
<table width="560" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background: #FFFFFF;margin: 0 auto !important; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; width:560px !important; line-height: 100% !important; border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"  >
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table width="560" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin: 0 auto !important; width:560px !important; line-height: 100% !important; border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"  >
                                        <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="40" valign="top" align="center" style="width: 100%; background: #000000; text-align: left; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 10px;">
                                                <span style="color: white;">5th Mar, 2016</span>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>

                        </table>
```

I want the output as displayed in the image.

[image: Here is the image]

Thank You.

Comment: Your snippet is producing the output you want. Whats your question?

Comment: so what exactly is the problem ? your code seems to do exactly what you want. maybe use background on `tr` instead of the `td` ?

Comment: When I give black BG to **5th Mar, 2016** then white BG doesn't appear.

Comment: well that's because the table only has one tr and one td ....tr expands on the whole width of the table. so if you add a bck to the row, it will cover the whole table

Comment: yeah.. so how can i overcome this issue?

Comment: done.. I have reduce the size of inner `table`. from 560 to 550. is it good to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have worked it out. Let me know if this helps. Thanks.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/rdg3gkL1/

```css
table {
  width: 560px;
  background: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-color: white;
}
td {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>5th Mar, 2016</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you.. Sazz.. but i cant' give padding . however i have solved it.. thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Hope This Helps

**HTML Code**

```
<table width="560">
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>5th Mar, 2016</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS Code**

```
table {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px
}

table, th, td {
 color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #000;
}
```